# how to test CMS page content of Rails 4 app using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec, comfortable-mexican-sofa

I installed Comfortable Mexican Sofa on a Rails 4 app and the visit function of my rspec tests was unable to find the CMS pages.  I found two remedies:  1) the following bash commands

```
pg_dump harvey_development > db.dump
psql harvey_test < db.dump
```

2) Adding the following to spec_helper.rb:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = 'development'
```

I suspect that a better solution would be to configure something such that rspec always used the development db to serve CMS content and used test db for everything else.  My question is:  What is the best solution to this problem?  And how do I implement it?  Thanks in advance for any help at all, even as little as a vague gesture in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look here: https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa/wiki/Docs:-CMS-Seeds#using-cms-seeds-in-tests

Also, depending on how you structure your tests, you can hit the fixture importer directly:
`ComfortableMexicanSofa::Fixture::Importer.new(from, to, :force).import!` Where `from` is the folder name and `to` is the identifier of the site.

Rake task works pretty good as it loads cms content only once for the duration of the entire test run. Also it doesn't get triggered if you're running focused tests. At least when using TestUnit, I don't like RSpec personally.

Comment: I appreciate your help.  I have been unable to get the importer to work in the test environment because I have been unable to figure out how to create a rake task.  I am going to have to put this issue off for another time, though, so I am going to mark this as solved.  Thanks again.

Comment: You keep rake stuff in `/lib/tasks/` just create `whatever.rake` file in there and you're good to go.

Comment: I have to use root permissions to create the fixtures.  Would I have to let the rake task have root permissions to import them to the test db?  If so, do you know how I would do that?

Comment: Why would you need root permissions to manage fixtures? Fixtures should have same access permission as the rest of the app files (as in not root)

Comment: I got the task to execute with:  bundle exec rake test:prepare.  For some reason, though, the fixtures are being imported into my development db.  Now I don't have to post that other question: "Why does stuff mysteriously disappear from my devel db?"

Comment: i just fixed link